# Diameter calculation

Tags: geometry

I've been killing myself with this. I got it down to one angle, but I can't determine that angle, so please, if anybody has any idea.

Thanks

Cylinder on the V frame.
V frame has an angle of 11$^o$ from horizontal, symmetric. Cylinder is laying on the frame. Height from top of the cylinder to the lowest point of the V frame is known. Only the diameter is needed.

Comment: From what I can tell, this looks like a high school geometry problem. Retagged accordingly.

Comment: Someone should translate this into human language. I feel insulted.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Is this the picture?]

Is this the picture?  (The rectangle being a side view of the cylindar.) I am not sure exactly what a $V$ frame is.  If this is the case, I think you would also need to know the length of the cylindar to find the diameter.

Comment: Neal's answer below is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

I take this to be the picture:
[image: cross-section]

where $D$ and angle $A$ are known, and $r$ needs to be found. The answer seems pretty straightforward once you construct a right triangle out of a radius and one of the $V$-frame legs. Just solve this equation for $r$:
$$D = r + \frac{r}{\sin(\pi/2 - A)} = r + \frac{r}{\cos(A)}.$$

Comment: I think you want $\sin(\pi/2-A)$ rather than $\cos(\pi/2-A)$ there.  (Since $r$ is the opposite side of the triangle in question.)  I was not able to make the edit because it required too few characters.

Comment: @Trevor Tsk, yes, thank you.